# how i can curl Range and User-Agent

Tags: php, curl

```
GET /folder/downloads/xx.zip HTTP/1.1
Range: bytes=0-6423263
User-Agent: Dalvik
Host: xx.xx.xxx.xxx:2050
Connection: Keep-Alive
Accept-Encoding: gzip
```

need to this in curl am try but is not work
can give me true code
i try

```
    $data = array('Range'=>"0-6423263");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://xx.xx.xxx.xxx:2050/folder/downloads/xx.zip");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Dalvik');
$output = curl_exec($curl);
```

Comment: _but is not work_ - So, what've you tried?

Comment: @Federico i try multi code

Comment: Edit your answer, and show us your efforts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` specify data to POST to server. Check [CURLOPT_RANGE](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_RANGE.html) instead.

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RANGE, '0-6423263');
```

By default curl use keep-alive by himself. You don't need to declare it.

For `Accept-Encoding` header, use `CURLOPT_ENCODING`

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip');
```